# Display Current Location Of Device on Map Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

I want to Dispaly Current Location Of Device on Map With  center of Map.How can I so this without using dependency service In **Xamarin.Forms** ??

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify which Map component you are using, so I assume you are using Xamarin Forms Maps.

If I understand your question correctly, there is a `IsShowingUser` property of the `Map` element that should provide the functionality that you are looking for.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map.IsShowingUser/